# How to solve type error when I add new fields to object in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I created an object. But when I try to set some values in it an error is thrown.
See code below:

```
function CheckStatus(oldJob, newJob) {
  var obj = {};
  if(newJob && newJob.Status) { 
    if (oldJob.Status.total !== newJob.Status.total) {
      obj.Status.total = newJob.Status.total;
    }
    if (oldJob.Status.charge_description && oldJob.Status.charge_description !== newJob.Status.charge_description) {
      obj.Status.charge_description = newJob.Status.charge_description;
    }
  }
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'total' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your definition of `obj` is an empty object. So before setting `obj.Status.total` you need to define `obj.Status`, either in the original declaration like so:

`var obj = {
  Status: {}
}`

or later like so:

`obj.Status = {}`

Answer (score 0):

Your obj variable has nos property status ! you must create his real structure before !

use lodash _.set :

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

function CheckStatus(oldJob, newJob) {
    let obj = {};
    if (newJob && newJob.Status) {
        if (oldJob.Status.total !== newJob.Status.total) {
            _.set(obj, 'Status.total', newJob.Status.total);
        }
        if (oldJob.Status.charge_description && (oldJob.Status.charge_description !== newJob.Status.charge_description)) {
            _.set(obj, 'Status.charge_description', newJob.Status.charge_description);
        }
    }
}
```

FYI it return a mutated object not a new object ! ;)